# Angular 2 nativeElement.focus doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to achieve `focus` on my input on another `element click`. Everything works on the computer, **but on mobile it isn't working**.
This is how I do it:

**Icon** that triggers `responsive()` function which calls `focus` on `input`:

```
<i (click)="responsive()" class="material-icons search-iko">search</i>
```

**Input:**

```
<input type="text" #inputas>
```

**Function:**

```
@ViewChild('inputas') inputas: ElementRef;
responsive() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.inputas.nativeElement.focus();
  }, 1);
}
```

On mobile - focus works just like CSS, not triggering the keyboard (you need to tap if you want to write).

***This input has two style versions onfocus and without focus. After responsive() function onfocus style appears but it's not focused only on mobile.*

**Try v2 (also tried with angular renderer) same result:**

```
private renderer: Renderer2
this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.inputas["nativeElement"]).focus();
```

***As I discovered javascript focus() isn't working on all mobile browsers:***

[htmlElement.focus browser support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqpZF.png)

Is there any other way of focusing input on mobile, like in **[www.imdb.com](http://www.imdb.com)** (click on the search icon)?

Comment: Have you tryied: <i (click)="inputas.focus()" ....> ?

Comment: Will try and write a feedback on that.

Comment: Yes, please give a feedback

Comment: Sorry, but onClick function will not work for me because I have to call my function when resoliution changes, not on click.

Comment: resposnive function just checks for resoliution and sets to true if mobile or false. Icon and search are not in the same component they share data.

Comment: If you need  focus() as mandatory after some check in `responsive` then you can do <i (click)="responsive();inputas.focus()" ....>. This is a shortcut solution. If you need to focus upon a condition in `responsive` then there are other, longer solutions

Comment: My question was not about how to focus after something, but that focus isnt working on mobile phones. Try it.

Comment: I understand well your question. My answer/help was about focus itself